# Excel to JSON format with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet which is in the below format

[image]

I want to convert this excel sheet into JSON format using Python. each JSON object is a diagonal value and column headings in the below format.

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "RecordId": "F1",
        "Assets": [
            {
                "AssetId": "A1",
                "Support": "S11"
            },
            {
                "AssetId": "A2",
                "Support": "S12"
            },
            {
                "AssetId": "A3",
                "Support": "S13"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "RecordId": "F2",
        "Assets": [
            {
                "AssetId": "A1",
                "Support": "S21"
            },
            {
                "AssetId": "A2",
                "Support": "S22"
            },
            {
                "AssetId": "A3",
                "Support": "S23"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I have written some code it seems not working as I expected.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_excel (r'test.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet2')
#initialize data
data=[0 for i in range(len(df))]
datac=[0 for c in range(len(df.columns))]
newset=dict()


for i in range(len(df)):
    # data[i] = r'{"'+str(df.columns.values[0])+'": "' +str(df.loc[i][0])+'", '+str(df.columns.values[1])+'": "' +str(df.loc[i][1])+'", '+str(df.columns.values[2])+'": "' +str(df.loc[i][2])+'"}' 
    #data[i] = {str(df.columns.values[1]) : str(df.loc[i][0]), str(df.columns.values[1]):  str(df.loc[i][1]), str(df.columns.values[2]): str(df.loc[i][2])}
    for c in range(1,len(df.columns)):
        #data[i] = {str('RecordId') : str(df.loc[i][0]),str('Assets'):[{"AssetId": str(df.columns.values[c]),"Support": str(df.loc[i][c])}]}
        datac[c] = {"AssetId": str(df.columns.values[c]),"Support": str(df.loc[i][c])}
    data[i]={str('RecordId') : str(df.loc[i][0]),str('Assets'):datac[c]}
    print(data[i])
output_lines = [json.dumps(line)+",\n" for line in data]
output_lines[-1] =   output_lines[-1][:-2] # remove ",\n" from last line
with open(r'Savedwork.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json_file.writelines(output_lines)
```

Comment: What is the output you're getting specifically? Is it an error or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the `iterrows()` method, it will iterate over the
dataframe's rows as (index, series) pairs. The `columns()` method will give you
the list of column names, so you'll be able to iterate over the columns in the
series, and access them by name.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

recs = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    rec = {
        'RecordId': row[0],
        'Assets': [{'AssetId': c, 'Support': row[c]} for c in df.columns[1:]]
    }
    recs.append(rec)

out = {'Records': recs}
```

(yes, it could all be done in a single list comprehension, but abusing those hinders readability)

Also, you don't need to do `json.dumps` on lines, and then assemble them with
newlines (don't work at the text level): build a dictionary with the entire
data, and then json.dump that:

```
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the dicts directly in pandas.
First set the first column with `F1, F2` as index:

```
df.set_index(0, inplace = True)
df.index.name = None
```

Then create the dicts in pandas with dict keys as column names, export it to a dict and save it to json:

```
import json
df = df.apply(lambda x: [{"AssetId": x.name, "Support": i} for i in x], axis =1).reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'RecordId', 0: 'Assets'})
json_data = {"Records": df.to_dict('records')}
with open('r'Savedwork.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_data, fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is to take a snapshot of the entire workbook in json format and reorganize it out of the box. Using the collect function of [XLtoy](https://github.com/glaucouri/XLtoy) is possible to do that via command line, this approach allows you more degrees of freedom.

[i'm the main developer of XLtoy]